# jQuery vertical itoggle switch?

Tags: jquery

I was wondering if it was possible to have a vertical jquery switch like the [itoggle](http://labs.engageinteractive.co.uk/itoggle/) instead of horizontal.

Anyone know of any resource or code snippet?

Thankyou

Comment: It's the same theory/code, you just have to create and/or modify the graphics.